# MVC Identity RemoveFromRole not removes correct role

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, roles

I am trying delete `Role` from `AspNetUserRoles` table, but Identity removed wrong role.

Scenario: Member has 2 roles as `"admin"` and `"user"`. I sent parameters from view `"userid=f134d34634dsscetc & rol=user"`

```
 public ActionResult RolSil(string userid, string rol, DbDataContext context)

    {
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationUserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

        var userInRole1 = userManager.IsInRole(userid, rol);

        if (userInRole1)
        {
            userManager.RemoveFromRole(userid, rol);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("KullaniciDetay", new { id = userid });
    }
```

It wasn't removed role that I sent "user",it removes "admin". There are some topics about it, says "This is a bug in IdentityManager , update Nuget Package for correct it".

I updated package to Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.1.0 so , but it isn't resolve my problem.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Problem Resolved.There are many topics about this but they not talking about "we need 2 updates"

Identity.Core update is not enough to resolve this problem. For this issue we must update Identity.EntityFramework too.

Nuget Links:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/2.1.0
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.1.0